# How to count only new errors by ID in a range of columns?

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr

I have a dataframe as the following: (With a lot more columns and rows to evaluate)

```
ID  COL1  COL2 COL3 COL4
1     x    x            
2          x         x  
3                      
4     x              x
5                x
```

I would like to obtain the sum of appearances of X in the columns 1 - 4 **NOT COUNTING PREVIOUS APPEARANCES FOR EACH ID**, for the example given above the answer would be:

```
  COL1  COL2 COL3 COL4
   2      1    1   0
```

***I elaborate:*** I count **ALL** the errors on column 1 for each ID, then I proceed to the second column and find that although there are two marks in that column, one belongs to ID 1, that already has been accounted for in column 1. For that reason, column 2 gets only 1 new appearance, column three has only one error and column 4 has no new errors, since both the appearances in that column have already been accounted for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one base R approach, we first get row and column values for elements where `"x"` is present in `mat`. We remove `duplicated` row values from it and so only the unique one stays for later columns. Finally using `table` we count the frequency of rows which are unique in each column.

```
mat <- as.data.frame(which(df[-1] == "x", arr.ind = TRUE))
new_mat <- mat[!duplicated(mat$row), ]
table(factor(new_mat$col, levels = seq_len(ncol(df[-1]))))

#1 2 3 4 
#2 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this much easily and in a compact way (one-liner)

```
rowSums(apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), "")) == "x")
# COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 
#  2    1    1    0
```

---

Or with `sapply`

```
rowSums(sapply(as.data.frame(t(df1[-1])), function(x) !duplicated(x) & x == "x"))
#[1] 2 1 1 0
```

---

or another option is `max.col`

```
table(factor(max.col(df1[-1] == 'x', 'first') * 
          NA^!rowSums(df1[-1] == 'x'), levels = 1:4))
# 1 2 3 4 
#2 1 1 0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, COL1 = c("x", "", "", "x", ""), COL2 = c("x", 
"x", "", "", ""), COL3 = c("", "", "", "", "x"), COL4 = c("", 
"x", "", "x", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

gather(df, key, val, -ID) %>%
  distinct(ID, val, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  filter(val == 'x') %>%
  count(key) %>%
  complete(key = names(df %>% select(-ID)),
           fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  spread(key, n)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
   COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     1     1     0
```